# How to override a hash constant using instance_eval in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

How I can override a constant in a class with an `instance_eval` in a plugin?
This is the constant I want to override:

```
class MessageTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base

     TEMPLATE_KEYS = {

    :guardian=>{
      :guardian_full_name=>"guardian_full_name",
      :guardian_first_name=>"guardian_first_name",
      :guardian_last_name=>"guardian_last_name",
      :ward_full_name=>"ward_full_name",
      :guardians_relation=>"guardians_relation",
      :ward_batch_name=>"ward_batch_name",
      :ward_admission_number=>"ward_admission_number",
      :guardian_email=>"guardian_email",
      :guardian_mobile_phone_no=>"guardian_mobile_phone_no"
    }

  }
end
```

I want to add these values to the above constant from a plugin in Ruby on Rails.
This is what I tried, which failed:

```
module IndepthEinvoice

         module MessageTemplate
    def self.included(base)
      base.instance_eval do
        self.TEMPLATE_KEYS = {
          :guardian=>{
              :payment_link=>"payment_link",
              :ward_balance_fee=>"ward_balance_fee"
          }
      }
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Modify Duplicates or Clones Instead of Constants

Ruby won't actually stop you from re-assigning a constant; it will generally just issue a warning. Still, it's generally considered bad form to modify constants on purpose. Instead, you should use [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) or [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) to store your changes in a local Hash object. For example:

```
TEMPLATE_KEYS = {
  guardian: {
    guardian_full_name:       "guardian_full_name",
    guardian_first_name:      "guardian_first_name",
    guardian_last_name:       "guardian_last_name",
    ward_full_name:           "ward_full_name",
    guardians_relation:       "guardians_relation",
    ward_batch_name:          "ward_batch_name",
    ward_admission_number:    "ward_admission_number",
    guardian_email:           "guardian_email",
    guardian_mobile_phone_no: "guardian_mobile_phone_no",
  }
}

# make a copy of your TEMPLATE_KEYS constant
@my_template = TEMPLATE_KEYS.dup

# merge your modifications into an instance variable
@my_template[:guardian].merge!(
  {
    payment_link:     "payment_link",
    ward_balance_fee: "ward_balance_fee",
  }
)

@my_template.dig :guardian, :payment_link
#=> "payment_link"
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, some more elegent than others. The principle is sound, though, and is definitely better than trying to modify the constant directly, which could have unintended consequences for your application.